# Changing AxesOrigin on a ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, visualization, labeling, plot-themes

How do you change the AxesOrigin to {0,0,0} for ListLinePlot3D?
The code I initially have looks like this

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j + i], {i, 1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

Which yields
[image]
Then when I add AxesOrigin->{0,0,0} as follows

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}], 
 Filling -> Bottom, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

I get
[image]
which hasnt changed the origin of the axes but rather has removed the axis all together. I'd ideally like the axes to look something like the example shown below
[image]

Any help would be most appreciated because this issue has been driving me crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your data does not consist of coordinates but rather just amplitudes corresponding to the default [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) of `{1, 16}` in the `x` and `y` dimensions. Rescale the axes to place the origin within the `DataRange`.

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[j^2 + i],
  {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 AxesStyle -> Thick,
 DataRange -> {{0, 2.8}, {0, 2.8}}]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[j^2 + i],
  {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 AxesStyle -> Thick,
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Or specify an origin within the default `DataRange`

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[j^2 + i],
  {i, 0, 3, 0.2}, {j, 0, 3, 0.2}],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 AxesOrigin -> {8, 8, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]